# Как сохранить состояние в flutter bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart

я начал изучать BLoC паттерн ( flutter_bloc plugin ) и не могу понять как сохранить выбранную состоянию.
Я начал делать приложения, а именно прогноз погоды. Конкретно в моем примере initialState будет один город.
После того как пользователь выберет другой город, нужно чтобы при открытии приложения ( после закрытии ), в экране показывался именно выбранный город. Как мне этого добиться с Bloc паттерном.

Мой код:

```
class WeatherBloc extends Bloc<WeatherEvent, WeatherState> {
 final WeatherRepository weatherRepository;
 WeatherBloc({this.weatherRepository}) : super(Weatherinitial());

@override
Stream<WeatherState> mapEventToState(
 WeatherEvent event,
 ) async* {
 if (event is FetchWeather) {
  yield WeatherLoading();
  try {
    WeatherModel weatherModel =
        await weatherRepository.getWeather(event.latlan);
    yield WeatherLoaded(weatherModel: weatherModel);
  } catch (_) {
    yield WeatherError();
  }
}
```

}
}

UI:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocProvider<WeatherBloc>(
    create: (context) =>
        WeatherBloc(weatherRepository: WeatherRepository()),
    child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: HexColor('ffffff'),
        body: BlocBuilder<WeatherBloc, WeatherState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is Weatherinitial) {
              return WeatherUI();
            }
            if (state is WeatherLoading) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (state is WeatherLoaded) {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text(state.weatherModel.temp.toString()),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text(state.weatherModel.isDay.toString()),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            return Text('Error');
          },
        )));
   }
}
```

Comment: [hydrated_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc), [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Comment: @MiT  Я имел ввиду только выбор города пользователем, а не  все что отображается в экране

Comment: два последних позволят сохранять то, что нужно.